# dhcp server won't send options

Tags: networking, proxy, dhcp

I have installed isc-dhcp-server on one machine and configured to send wpad address:

```
option local-proxy-config code 252 = text;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ## dhcp start  and end IP range ##
    range 192.168.1.140 192.168.1.144;
    option local-proxy-config "http://www.example.org/proxy.pac";

    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;     ## subnet 
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255; ## broadcast
    option routers 192.168.1.1; ## router IP
```

}

then did dhcpd -t and restarted server, and then I wanted to test the option from another machine, so I used dhcping:

```
sudo dhcping -iV -s 192.168.1.98 -h 01:02:03:04
```

which gave me:

```
op: 2
htype: 1
hlen: 4
hops: 0
xid: b8990b59
secs: 0
flags: 0
ciaddr: 0.0.0.0
yiaddr: 0.0.0.0
siaddr: 192.168.1.98
giaddr: 0.0.0.0
chaddr: 01:02:03:04:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
sname : .
fname : .
option 53 DHCP message type
    DHCP message type: 5 (DHCPACK)
option 54 Server identifier
    Server identifier: 192.168.1.98
option 1 Subnet mask
    Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
close
```

server didn't log any warning or something:

```
May  5 01:12:43 node2 dhcpd: DHCPACK to 192.168.1.251 (01:02:03:04) via eth0
May  5 01:14:31 node2 dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 192.168.1.251 via eth0
```

can anyone please tell me why am I not getting 252 option?

Answer (score 5):

By default, client has to request the option for the server to send it.

You can use these lines in the dhcpd.conf file to force some options:

```
if exists dhcp-parameter-request-list {
  option dhcp-parameter-request-list = concat(option dhcp-parameter-request-list,fc);
}
```

Note: code 252 = 0xfc

Comment: I want to force option 209 (equal 0xd1), but it doesn't work.
In wireshark I can see that in DHCP ACK there is no 209 option.
Does it matter in which part of /etc/dhcpd.conf that construction resides?

Comment: thank you so much this was driving me crazy   